# Why does OleFlushClipboard cause my storage object to lose its class id?

Tags: c#, windows, clipboard, ole

I have implemented an `IDataObject` which writes the "Embedded Object" data to an `IStorage` medium along with a `METAFILEPICT` and an `OBJECTDESCRIPTOR` for the preview. The object is passed to the clipboard with `OleSetClipboard`.

I can paste this in to Word but if I call `OleFlushClipboard` pasting fails with error "Word has encountered a problem". If I fetch the object's `IStorage` I can see its class id has been reset to `CLSID_NULL` after flushing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

In the end the problem was solved by call `IStorage::Commit` after writing the ClsID. Obviously for some reason in my particular use case the changes weren't being written properly to the underlying storage given to us by the clipboard.